# Nested foreach not working

Tags: knockout.js

I am beginner in knockout and writing a sample application in which I have to display parent child relations.

So for that I have two foreach loops. One of them iterate through parents and another one is children of each parents. Basically `nested foreach` loop. But when I use nested loop, data is not being rendered.

Below is my sample html which is not working for `Children` loop:

```
<div class='liveExample'> 
  <div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <div class="parent" data-bind="text: Name">
      <div class="children" data-bind="foreach: Children">
        <div data-bind="text: Name"></div>
        <div data-bind="text: Age"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In found similar stackoverflow questions and based on the answer provided, I tried with **$parent.Children**. But that also doesn't work in my case.

Here is the [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wfs569gf/)

> **Observation**: One of my observation of not working is because foreach
>   is defined inside `<div class="parent" data-bind="text: Name">` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your children within the same element that you're using the `text` binding on - this won't work, since that binding will replace the entire contents with what it's bound to - in this case the parent Name.  That's why you're not seeing any of the children - the markup is simply lost.

You need to move the children and the parent name binding away from each other:

You could move them outside of the parent div:

```
<div class='liveExample'> 
  <div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <div class="parent" data-bind="text: Name">
    </div>
    <div class="children" data-bind="foreach: Children">
      <div data-bind="text: Name"></div>
      <div data-bind="text: Age"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you could use an extra span to contain the parent name:

```
<div class='liveExample'> 
  <div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <div class="parent">
      <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
      <div class="children" data-bind="foreach: Children">
        <div data-bind="text: Name"></div>
        <div data-bind="text: Age"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or any other approach that keeps the hierarchy as you need it, so long as the element with the `text` binding is otherwise kept empty.

Comment: I would go with your second suggestion. But the code I provided is just a sample code. In actual case I have widget for collapsible panel. and inside that panel, my code for children resides.

Comment: Right - in that case, yes - keeping them contained within the parent div is logical

Comment: is there any option like `$parent`

Comment: Well, there is a `$parent` available within child bindings, yes, but I'm not sure why you'd want to use it here.

Comment: Actually I must have to place that html inside `<div class="parent" data-bind="text: Name">` as it is a collapsible panel for me. And `name` is the title of that panel. But logically thinking, It is not possible as those html would considered to be child of `Name`. But still if there is any hack for this.

Comment: You simply can't - the text binding will remove the inner markup.  You will need to redesign the collapsing panels to take this into account.